# Why is ctx.strokeRect() behaving differently than sequential ctx.rect() ctx.stroke() calls

Tags: reactjs, canvas, crop

I created a React app using create-react-app. In this app, a user uploads a picture that is drawn to the canvas. This app allows the user to crop the image, and I'm trying to draw a rectangle preview of the cropped area as the user mouse-drags over the image.

Here is the function that draws the dynamic crop-area preview. This one works well because it is using `ctx.strokeRect()`. Every time the user moves the mouse, `rectXY` gets updated, and calls `drawCropRect` to clear the previous rectangle and make a new one.

```
    // draw rectangle preview of cropped area
  const drawCropRect = (
    canvasRef,
    rectXY,
    croppedCanvasData
  ) => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.putImageData(croppedCanvasData,0,0, 0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#f6dd43";
    // calling strokeRect() - this works
    ctx.strokeRect(
      rectXY.xStart,
      rectXY.yStart,
      rectXY.xCurrent - rectXY.xStart,
      rectXY.yCurrent - rectXY.yStart
    );
  };

  // calls drawCropRect when the user is dragging the mouse to crop image 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.step === "crop") {
      drawCropRect(canvasRef, cropRect, croppedCanvasData[0]);
    }
  }, [cropRect]);
  // cropRect is a state hook containing starting and current mouse positions
// drawCropRect will get called every time cropRect updates.. so whenever the user moves the mouse during a crop event.
```

However, if instead of calling `ctx.strokeRect()`, I called `ctx.rect()` and then `ctx.stroke()`, the rectangles are not cleared, and I see all of the rectangles generated on the image.

[image: picture of many crop rectangles - but there should only be one!]

Here is the same function but with calling separate `ctx.rect()` and `ctx.stroke()`.

```
  // draw rectangle preview of cropped area
  const drawCropRect = (canvasRef, rectXY, croppedCanvasData) => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.putImageData(
      croppedCanvasData,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      canvas.width,
      canvas.height
    );
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#f6dd43";
    // calling rect() and then stroke()- this does not work
    ctx.rect(
      rectXY.xStart,
      rectXY.yStart,
      rectXY.xCurrent - rectXY.xStart,
      rectXY.yCurrent - rectXY.yStart
    );
    ctx.stroke();
  };
```

Why is this happening? How does calling separate `ctx.rect()` and `ctx.stroke()` prevent them from being cleared when the user moves the mouse?

Comment: You need to use `ctx.beginPath()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ctx.beginPath()` at the start of the `rect()` section of `drawCropRect()`.

If you don't use `ctx.beginPath()` it throws off the canvas.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I put ctx.beginPath(); right before ctx.rect() and ctx.stroke() and it works perfectly. Such a quick answer :)